# Maui RestAPI Response dont work with Android

Tags: c#, android, rest, database-connection, maui

Hey i use RestSharp to Get data from my Database, if i run this with Windows Application this works perfectly and flawless but if i run this with my Android (it should primary work there instead of Windows) there happens just nothing.

Code stopps at RestRespone without error, in Debug it also stops and do nothing.
What is it, do I need a different syntax?

Permission is set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

---

Viewmodel:

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(GetUrl);
RestResponse restResponse = restClient.Get(restRequest); // <-- Stuck point

using (DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(restResponse.Content, (typeof(DataTable))))
{

    CultureInfo german = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
    firmen = (from DataRow row in dt.Rows
              select new FirmenKunden()
              {
                  Id_Terminliste = row["id_Terminliste"].ToString(),
                  Id_Firma = row["id_Firma"].ToString(),
                  Termin = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Termin"]).ToString("ddd'. 'dd'.'MM'.'yyyy' 'HH:mm", german),
                  TerminTagZahl = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Termin"]).ToString("dd"),
                  TerminUnFormatted = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Termin"]),
                  ServiceSafe = row["ServiceSafe"].ToString(),
                  Beschreibung = row["Beschreibung"].ToString(),
                  ServiceNr = row["ServiceNr"].ToString(),
                  MassnahmenNr = row["MassnahmenNr"].ToString(),
                  Servicestand = row["Servicestand"].ToString(),
                  Firma = row["Firma"].ToString(),
                  Strasse = row["Strasse"].ToString(),
                  Postleitzahl = row["Postleitzahl"].ToString(),
                  Ort = row["Stadt"].ToString(),
                  Vertragsbeginn = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Vertragsbeginn"]).ToString("ddd'. 'dd'.'MM'.'yyyy", german),
                  Vertragsende = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Vertragsende"]).ToString("ddd'. 'dd'.'MM'.'yyyy", german)

              }).ToList();
}
```

---

Also tried this:

```
var options = new RestClientOptions(GetUrl)
     {
         ThrowOnAnyError = true,
         MaxTimeout = 100000
     };
     var restClient = new RestClient(options);
```

---

My Controller:

```
public function getFirmaTermin($id_Firma = null) {
    if($id_Firma != null && is_numeric($id_Firma)) {
        return \DB::table('Terminliste')
        ->join('Firmen', 'Terminliste.id_Firma', '=', 'Firmen.id') 
        ->select('Terminliste.*', 'Firmen.*')
        ->where('id_Firma', $id_Firma)
        ->get();
    }
    return \DB::table('Terminliste')
        ->join('Firmen', 'Terminliste.id_Firma', '=', 'Firmen.id') 
        ->select('Terminliste.*', 'Firmen.*')
        ->get();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it’s not timing out?  Is your server running on localhost?

Comment: No i have a WebServer, it works on all platforms, but if i try to build this in my Maui project as Android it just dont response.

Comment: Are you sure you are waiting long enough for a timeout exception to occur?  Have you verified connectivity to your server from the Android device or emulator using the browser?  (NOT the desktop browser)

Comment: i edited my code and adds this section : "Also tried this:"

Comment: There do not come any exception, code forwards and display me a empty listview, i can now press the backbutton to show me the site before and reproduce the step without any exceptions

Comment: You didn't answer the questions I asked, and **increasing** the timeout value will just make it harder to determine if that is the actual problem

Comment: And i answered 4 hours ago : i edited my code and adds this section : "Also tried this:".. Just give a look to my edited post. i increased the timout to 100000.

Comment: "Have you verified connectivity to your server..." - not answered.  And as I pointed out, increasing the timeout value does nothing to help identify if it really is a timeout problem.

Comment: 1) Tested on an actual Android device? 2) I wouldn't "press back button and reproduce step w/o any exceptions" - once something has gone wrong the first time, any further communication tests on that app run are not meaningful, imho.

Comment: Does your server send chunked data ?

Comment: Seems to work now after VS Preview Update to 17.4.0  Thanks to all